# What is Excon[api.heroku.com]: GET?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, newrelic

I'm looking my most time consuming transaction on New Relic right now. And I see that "Excon[api.heroku.com]: GET" takes up the majority of the time required. What is it? And how can I reduce it?

> Category  |   Segment % | Time |  Avg calls(per txn) | Avg time (ms)
>
> External  Excon[api.heroku.com]: GET | 34.3 | 0.653 | 133
>
> View | projects/show.html.erb Template | 9.9  | 0.997 | 38.5
>
> Controller | ProjectsController#show | 9.3 | 1.0 | 36.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an external HTTP request to `api.heroku.com`. External HTTP calls generally introduce additional execution time because of the IO.

If you want to reduce it you need to determine why your action connects to Heroku and if you can either cache or replace the request.